# Is there an advantage of using indirection when including a module (from 7 Languages In 7 Weeks, Ruby day 3)

Tags: ruby, inheritance, module, metaprogramming

Bruce gives the following example in "Seven languages in seven weeks", Ruby day 3, page 38:

```
module ActsAsCsv
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def acts_as_csv
      include InstanceMethods
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def read
       #fill @csv_contents and @headers from file self.class.to_s.downcase + '.txt'
    end

    attr_accessor :headers, :csv_contents

    def initialize
      read
    end
  end
end

class RubyCsv
  include ActsAsCsv
  acts_as_csv
end

m = RubyCsv.new
puts m.headers.inspect
puts m.csv_contents.inspect
```

I do not see any reason for the indirection used by `def self.included(base)` and `ClassMethods`. Is there an advantage of the above code over simply including the module InstanceMethods?

---

In detail: With "simply including the module InstanceMethods" I mean the following code:

```
  module InstanceMethods #defined as above
    def read
       #fill @csv_contents and @headers from file self.class.to_s.downcase + '.txt'
    end

    attr_accessor :headers, :csv_contents

    def initialize
      read
    end    
  end

class RubyCsv
  include InstanceMethods
end

m = RubyCsv.new
puts m.headers.inspect
puts m.csv_contents.inspect
```

Because of duck typing, isn't this just as good as going via `base.extend ClassMethods`?

Comment: Btw, this might be considered a double post of http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/147/topics/8445?page=1#posts-27675. Since that one has not been answered for almost a year (and I'm spoiled by the speed and quality of Stackoverflow answers:) and this post is more thorough, I hope nobody minds...

Comment: The advantage is communication.

Comment: Communication? What information between what entities?

Comment: Purpose, between the code, and people reading the code.

Comment: And how is additional code and indirection making the purpose more readable?

Comment: Moved to answer; too long for comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original code allows you to do this:

```
class A
  include ActsAsCsv
end

class B < A
  acts_as_csv
end
```

While using inheritance is more a matter of taste in this case it would be cleaner if

- more methods than just `acts_as_csv` would be added similarly to `A`
- `ActsAsCsv` would be expected to be included by a class from which many classes inherit (like some kind of `BaseModel`)

Further advantage arise when

- the method `acts_as_csv` is more elaborate than just including `InstanceMethods`
- `acts_as_csv` takes an argument, for example `acts_as_csv :separator => " "`

Comment: Thanks obrok (+1) I edited your answer to hopefully make it even clearer for readers - hope I interpreted your reasons correctly. Could you give a link to `BaseModel`, please?

Comment: @DaveBall There is no `BaseModel`, that's an example of a base class that might include `ActsAsCsv`, the same way Rails models include modules that allow things like `has_many` etc.

Comment: Oh, that's why I didn't find it then ;) Thx for clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

One advantage is communication of purpose, between the code (and original writer) and those reasoning about the code later. (And the mechanics of allowing parameters.)

`acts_as_csv` states an aspect of `RubyCsv`'s behavior.

`include ActsAsCsv` is less declarative. Does it provide additional methods, does it fundamentally alter the functionality of the underlying class, or both, or...? You won't know until you read the docs. You might not know until you read the docs for `acts_as_csv`, either, but it's more communicative.

It's the difference between "this is what I am", and "this is what I may do". Don't get caught up in the specific example–consider the mechanics of what is being done, and how.

This mechanism is one reason Ruby code can look like the problem it's trying to solve instead of just Ruby. It's one way of implementing the micro-DSLs that help make Ruby as expressive as it is.